How should we define equivariant $G$-module over a ring?
Let $A$ be a commutative ring with identity. Now suppose we have a finite group $G$ where $G$ acts $A$ on the left (the action may not be trivial). Suppose we have a $A$-module $M$, I wonder what is the correct definition for $M$ to be a $G$-equivariant module? I think first $M$ should be a $G$-module. However, I am confused what is the  compatibility
condition between the $G$-action on $A$ and $G$-action on $M$.
If we realize $A$ as a left $G$-module, it should satisfy $g\cdot (ab)=(g\cdot a)(g \cdot b)$. So in general, the action should satisfy $g(am)=(ga)(gm)$.
However, from the "equivariant sheaf" of wikipedia, it seems $M$ is a $G$-euqivariant sheaf if there is a group homomorphism $G\to \operatorname{End}_{A}(M)$. This suggests $g\cdot(am):=a (g\cdot m) $. However, if we use this definition, it seems $G$-action on $A$ and $G$-action on $A$ are irrelevant.
From this answer:What the exact definition of coherent $G-$ sheaf?. It seems $g\cdot(am):=(g^{-1}\cdot a)(g\cdot m)$.
I am very confused now. Can you tell me what is the correct definition?

I think in general there is no relation between G-action on A and G-action on M. So you may ask the following question which is more natural: "given an G-action on A and an A-module M, how to define a natural G-action on M?" Even this question has no unique answer, for example, you can always use the trivial G-action on M. But to make this G-action compatible with the action on A, I think the last definition is the one.
